# Can AWS lambda function receive many requests in one run?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm making NodeJS script which asks user for authorisation, using AWS Lambda to deploy it. First of all script needs the phone number, then sends SMS message with code user should insert. Then script do some stuff without user's intervention. So, the script triggers on POST request with phone number using API gateway. Is it possible to make second request with SMS code using only one lambda function?

Comment: You would need to make a second request separate for handling the SMS code.

Comment: @Chris I know) And I'm asking about possibility to make second request to the same function after the first request is made

Comment: You'd have to make it so your lambda checks for a provided code in the payload sent, and if it exists then try to verify, and if it doesn't exist then you'd check for a phone number and do your regular sending of SMS code. This would be two separate executions though. You wouldn't be able to have both requests use the same execution.

Comment: If your question is "can a client make two independent API requests via API Gateway which are handled by the same instance of a Lambda function?", then no, not to my knowledge. If you need to maintain state between Lambda invocations, then a common solution is to send state to the client in the 1st response so it can re-submit it with the 2nd request, or use DynamoDB.